# Jhipster : get application-dev properties value

Tags: jhipster

In Java I need to get the values of mail properties (username, password, port, host, etc.) in application-dev.yml file.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't get your question. Could you explain a bit more? Do you want to set username, password, port, host in your app-dev.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I re-read your question and saw that you are trying to set/retrieve mail properties. These are common Spring Boot properties and you do not need to deal with custom properties. Here is how to retrieve them from your application:

```
spring:
    mail:
        username: realUsername
```

.

```
@Service
public class ExampleService {

    @Inject
    private MailProperties mailProperties;

    public void exampleMethod() {
        mailProperties.getUsername();
    }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

JHipster creates a class for these custom properties called `JHipsterProperties` that you can inject into your beans. For example:

```
@Service
public class ExampleService {

    @Inject
    private JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    public void exampleMethod() {
        jHipsterProperties.getMail().getFrom();
    }
}
```

You can extend `JHipsterProperties` (and its inner classes) with whatever you want. Stripped down example:

```
jhipster:
    mail:
        username: realUsername
```

.

```
public class JHipsterProperties {

    private final Mail mail = new Mail();

    public static class Mail {

        private String username = "defaultUsername";

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }
    }
}
```

This can then be used in your beans like `jHipsterProperties.getMail().getUsername();`

However, I would recommend creating your own properties class and configuring Spring to use that for your custom properties instead. I prefer to leave JHipster-specific code alone so I have less work to do when upgrading my JHipster version.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to set a username, password, port and host in your app-dev.yml.

```
spring:
profiles:
    active: dev
datasource:
    driverClassName: com.nuodb.jdbc.Driver
    dataSourceClassName: com.nuodb.jdbc.DataSource
    url: jdbc:com.nuodb://localhost:48004/test?schema=HOCKEY
    databaseName: test
    serverName: localhost
    username: dba
    password: goalie
    cachePrepStmts: true
    prepStmtCacheSize: 250
    prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
    useServerPrepStmts: true

jpa:
    database-platform: org.nuodb.hibernate.NuoDBDialect
    database: test
    openInView: false
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
    properties:
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: true
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
messages:
    cache-seconds: 1
thymeleaf:
    mode: XHTML
    cache: false

metrics:
    jmx.enabled: true
    graphite:
        enabled: false
        host: localhost
        port: 2003
        prefix: hockey

cache:
    timeToLiveSeconds: 3600
    ehcache:
        maxBytesLocalHeap: 16M
```

You can make changes in the app-dev.yml and do the same changes in your DatabaseConfiguration class. This should solve your problem.

And also, please let me know, are you trying to add new database to JHipster? or please let me know what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: That's not what I want to do. From a java class I want to access the value of the username, port, host, password, etc set in the application-dev.yml file. I have tried : Properties properties = System.getProperties();      properties.getProperty("mail.username"); but it doesn't work.